# Cannot solve this php loop

Tags: php, loops

I have a config.ini what I have to change by php so, I'm trying to change it by while bucles but I cannot fix it.
I have to delete some App1 user who I have in a variable $parametros["usuario"], its not always there so, It's not a poblem if 
he is not in this file (but I have to try to find him on App1 (appname=Microsoft Remote Desktop))

**so: I have to delete some user name saved in $parametros['user'] to the config.ini (only the app1)**

The config.ini looks like:

```
[App1]
    appname=Microsoft Remote Desktop
    path=
    startup=
    cmdline=
    groups=
    users=BOX\xavier.roch00;BOX\lealma01;BOX\bautij01;BOX\gonzad01
    maximized=
    minimized=
    hide=
    all_users=no
    [App2]
    appname=TSplus Remote Taskbar
    path=
    startup=
    cmdline=
    groups=
    users=
    maximized=
    minimized=
    hide=
    all_users=no
```

and I'm trying something like:

```
$appname = "appname=Microsoft Remote Desktop";
$users = "users="

$encontrado_liniaAppname = false;
$encontrado_liniaUsers = false;
$encontrado = false;
$indice = 0;

while (!$encontrado)
{
    if ($arrFiche[$indice] === $appname)
        $encontrado_liniaAppname = true;
    else if($encontrado_liniaAppname === true && $arrFichero[$indice] == $encontrado_liniaUsers)
    {
        $encontrado_liniaUsers = true;
        // borramos el usuario en caso de que exista en users
        str_replace($this->parametros["usuario"], "", $arrFichero[$indice]);
        $encontrado = true;
    }
    else
        $indice++;
}
```

I'm newbie so, It's hard for me... thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Hola Victor! This will require quite a lot of thinking, but you can first open the file for reading and writing, then strip out everything not related to the App1 part (maybe with `fgets()`) or even isolate the line you need, then search for a user match within the string so you can finally strip it out and save the file. There are many ways to do it and it's quite long... you might want to check out some functions like `fopen`, `fgets`, `fread`, `fwrite`, `fclose`, `preg_match` and `preg_replace`.

Comment: @Zeke if i put all the content in Array using file_get_content().... then i explode the results by \r\n... i do the change and then I implode it, how suposed can I save the changes? OR the implode() method does already it?

Comment: First of all, I speak Spanish very fluently, so if you need further help in such language, contact me through Twitter to get my email and we can discuss better... second, the issue with `file_get_contents()` is that it will only give you the content, but it won't let you overwrite the file. If you use the functions I listed above, you can open the file ready to read and write (read to get the content, write to overwrite the content) and then close it to save the changes. If not, you'll have to delete the file and then use the new string to create another new file.